# How to set focus to UserControl (make it selectable)?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus

I need to set focus to `UserControl` itself, not its child.
Otherwise I cannot implement insertion from the buffer. :(
Setting `Focusable=True` doesn't help.
Google and SO tells only how to set focus to UserControl child.

My control contains:
 - Toolbar with several buttons bound to commands of the corresponding
   VM
 - TextBox which is the input for the filter
 - DataGrid - list of items.

I need to bind Ctrl+V command to VM. But to handle this gesture `UserControl` must have focus within. When there are no items in the grid (VM's collection is empty) buttons are disabled and the only element which can get focus is `TextBox`. But it handles Ctrl+V in its own way and I don't want to change this behavior.
Thus, I need something to set focus to when I click the area of UserControl.
I believe UserControl is the best candidate for it.
But I don't know how to make it selectable.

Comment: `Otherwise I cannot implement insertion from the buffer` - Can you please explain this better? your question is too vague dude, I can't understand. Also post your current code and XAML.

Comment: I've added some details. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The whole problem was in my misunderstanding of controls' behavior.
This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600017/does-mouse-click-brings-keyboard-focus-to-focusable-control-by-default) clearly shows it I believe.

Thus, setting `UserControl.Focusable = true` is not sufficient. To make it navigatable via keyboard `IsTabStop` must be `true` also. And to make UC selectable by mouse click we should call `Focus()` in mouse eventhandler. That's it.

Comment: This is still not enough for me. I create a usercontrol (BigDropPin) and if I press "space" it should create other usercontrols (MiniDropPin).

Comment: @RafaelVentura: It looks like the space behavior of buttons is a special logic of buttons. You'll need to subscribe (or add a KeyBinding) for space separately. additional to making the UC focusable.