# Do mouse clicks bring keyboard focus to focusable controls by default?

Tags: wpf, focus

This question can seem quite odd but from all my experience I've gotten used to setting keyboard focus to the focusable element just by clicking it with the mouse; however, UserControl with the properties `Focusable = true` and `IsTabStop = true` came as a surprise to me because it gets keyboard focus via Tab but stays ignorant to mouse clicks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Handle the click event on the UserControl and add this code to the eventhandler:

```
private void UserControl_OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Keyboard.Focus(sender as UserControl);
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this isn't the default behavior? When would you *not* want a focusable control to get focus on a mouse click?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank It is a good question which I can only take a guess at. Personally I'm glad there isn't much automagic stuff in WPF.